# use ls to rm a list of files

Tags: find, ls, xargs, rm

I unzipped a large collection of documents and forgot to tick 'keep directory structure', so now trying to remove all those files. The files are in my Downloads folder with no folder structures.

I have unzipped the file again in a different location and tried the following command to remove the flat files.

```
for file in $(find . -type f -printf '~/Downloads/%f\n'); do rm $file; done
```

It says cannot remove file as it doesn't exist, but if I copy the path it spits out into `rm` it finds and removes it fine.

```
rm: cannot remove `/home/macpherson/Downloads/SN74LS14N': No such file or directory
```

Same results with `xargs`

Any ideas?

Thanks Tom

Comment: Can you please give us some examples how the files are organized in the archive and where they went to on your local file system?

Comment: In the archive they are in several folders with possibly many layers of sub-directories. They were extracted to ~/Downloads with no directory structure

Comment: Well that's not really an example … ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Extract the same archive somewhere else (where you can safely remove it afterwards if you want). Then use this to find which files have to be removed:

```
find . -type f | sed -e 's/.*\//\/home\/macpherson\/Downloads\//' | xargs rm
```

Comment: thanks! required extra \/ after Downloads. Also not sure this would work with files with spaces in their names